# How to OData Patch

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, odata, patch

I have a .net core 3.1 WEB Api service where I use OData (V4)
I have an endpoint where every query through GET METHOD is working fine, and with  the same endpoint I can use POST METHOD and insert new records to database.

The problem is, the DELETE and PATCH METHODs are not working (or maybe they are, but if I try to use update or delete I always get a 404 Not Found error). I try to call them ( DELETE, PATCH) from POSTMAN, but I get the same 404 error, however the methods are in the controller.

MyController:

```
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class UsersController : ODataController
{
    [HttpGet]
    [EnableQuery()]
    public IEnumerable<User> Get()
    {
        return new Context().Userek;
    }

    [HttpPatch]
    [EnableQuery]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Patch([FromODataUri] int id, Delta<User> user)
    {
        var ctx = new Context();

        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }
        var entity = await ctx.Userek.FindAsync(id);
        if (entity == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        user.Patch(entity);
        try
        {
            await ctx.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
        {
            if (id != 23)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            else
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
        return Updated(entity);
    }
    public async Task<IActionResult> Delete([FromODataUri] int id)
    {
        var ctx = new Context();

        var user = await ctx.Userek.FindAsync(id);
        if (user == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        ctx.Userek.Remove(user);
        await ctx.SaveChangesAsync();
        return StatusCode(404);
    }
}
```

Thank you for any help!

Comment: You are explicitly returning "return StatusCode(404);" on delete. And "return Updated(entity);" is not of type "IActionResult" on Patch.

Comment: Since you both return the `NotFound()` method (404 error) under certain conditions in the Delete and Patch methods, when a certain condition is met, a 404 error is returned.
`StatusCode (404) and NotFound () return the same result.`
I suggest that you use breakpoints to debug the code and confirm which piece of code is returned. If everything is normal, it is only related to the parameters you pass and the data in the database.

Comment: Thank you so much I will try!